# c# Buffer cannot be null. Parameter name: array

Tags: c#

I'm working on a Windows Service and I'm trying to write a `Byte[]` to a already existing File with a normal FileStream. My Code looks like this:

```
byte[] attachBytes = attach.Data;

FileInfo info = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\" + attach.Filename);

FileStream stream = info.Create();

stream.Write(attachBytes, 0, attachBytes.Length);
```

The exception message is:

> **Buffer cannot be null. Parameter name: array**

Has anyone an idea what's going on here?

Additional info: `byte[]` comes from a `.msg` file which I'm reading with this [library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32899/Reading-an-Outlook-MSG-File-in-C). I'm looping through the attachments of the `.msg` file and saving them in a directory. .NET 4.5.2, Desktop Enviroment. I've tested the code in a console application and it works perfectly. But in my WindowsService project the error occurs.
**EDIT:**
Stacktrace:

```
    Source: mscorlib Message: A call target caused an exception error. StackTrace:  
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)  
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)  
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)  
   at Source: mscorlib Message: Buffer cannot be null.
Parametername: array StackTrace:
   at System.IO.FileStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in the debugger and confirmed that `attach.Data` isn't actually `null`?

Comment: That's a bit weird. It sounds like `attachBytes` is `null`, but you should get `NullReferenceException` at `attachBytes.Length` even before the `stream.Write` is called.

Comment: @Diado attach.Data is definitly not null.

Comment: I tried exactly your code, but cannot reproduce it. What is your environment? Desktop or NetCore? which frameworkversion? Can you show the stacktrace of the exception, so not only exception.Message, but the whole exception.ToString()?

Comment: @gofal3 I updated my question

Comment: did some search for the stracktrace. similar exceptions with the same stracktrace have been posted and resolved, by copying missing assemblies to the GlobalAssemblyCache or into the executables directory. Also some exceptions throws in some eventhandler give this same stracktrace. But since your code works in console but not in service, try to find some missing assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code for the "public override void Write(byte[] array, int offset, int count)" method: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs line 1751. Granted the .NET version for the source code in the link is 4.7.2, I don't imagine the code being relevantly different for your error case.

The only time an ArgumentNullException is thrown from the FileStream.Write(...) is when the 'array' argument passed to the Write method is null.

Consider the possibility that 'attach.Data' may indeed be returning null. Is there anything special about 'attach.Data' that we should know about?

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. attach.Data is a attachment of .msg file. I referenced the library which I'm using in my question. Attach.Data is for 110% not null. I debugged it like 1000 times